# Saving pygame drawing

Tags: python, pygame

I have made a simple drawing/paint program using pygame. I was wondering if I could create a button that, when clicked, allows the drawing to be saved as a .png file and another button to open a .png file onto the pygame window to edit/draw on?

Will appreciate any support, thank you.